# How app connects to Chromecast for the first time?

Tags: android, chromecast

How does the android app detects Chromecast for the first time ? ie. When they both are not in the same network. 
I assuming the device initially acts as a hotspot, if so how come the app knows a device is actually a Chromecast ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official documentation at: 
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers

Chromecast has it own wifi hotspot used to spread his presence in the room! When a Device with the "Screen Mirroring" feature turned on discovers a Chromecast-style wifi hotspot it starts the setup of the link between itself and the Chromecast device.

Many devices like the Google Nexus 4 have a built-in function to setup and start a cast to Chromecast, many others like the Google Nexus 9 needs the "Chromecast App" form Google Play in order to setup the "cast link".

Comment: It doesnt answer how the app knows there is a "chromecast hotspot" out of all avialable hotspots.

Comment: Chromecasts devices have a known MAC address signature and sends out a beacon (like an heartbeat) via the wifi!